# CSS - How to keep full image visible regardless the viewport size?

Tags: html, css, image, cross-platform, viewport-units

I'm trying to display an image for mobile devices only, but when I resize the browser or select different mobile device my image resizes, which is not what I want. I use vh unit so my image looks the same on all widths. Here's the snippet:

```css
#main-pic {
        border: 2px solid red;
        background-image: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/736230/pexels-photo-736230.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500);
        height: 55vh;
        min-width: 100%;
        background-size: cover;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="main-pic"></div> 
</body>
</html>
```

In my real-life project, this photo is in Bootstrap grid and I use @media queries to specify the width of devices.

EDIT: To clarify, I want to display full image no matter what screen size it is

EDIT 2: Ok, so let's assume I'm trying to display the full image, keeping it's ratio - for every mobile device - in a grid (col-sm-10, taking it's full width), what would be the suggestions for making it look good?

Comment: What do you mean by looking the same? Do you want the image to be displayed in full? Do you want to keep the aspect ratio of the image? Do you want the image to be cropped?

Comment: with `background-size: cover` your image resizes, if neccesary. Remove/replace that line

Comment: It's not clear what the issue is. You've selected `background-size: cover;` what are you expecting to happen?

Comment: I want it to display full image on every device, but still keep it in a grid

Comment: So you want the div to resize to the size of the background image which then adapts to viewport size? You can't do that with CSS.

Comment: You do know that if you choose to display the full image AND keep the aspect ratio, it's not going to fill the full width since you set the height to be a fraction of a (variable) viewport height?

Comment: @J4R it didn't solve the issue

Comment: are you aware of `background-size: contain` ?

Comment: Frankly, to get what you want, this should **not** be a background-image... it should be an **actual** image

Comment: @Paulie_D so what would it look like

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Ok, so let's assume I'm trying to display the full image, keeping it's
>   ratio - for every mobile device - in a grid (col-sm-10, taking it's
>   full width), what would be the suggestions for making it look good?

Use `background-size: contain`

(Additionally you could use a background-color to fill the areas of the `div` which are not covered by the background-image).

Comment: works fine, but now my text that was under the image goes beneath the picture

Comment: there is no text in your sample code, and also your question doesn't mention any text...

Comment: you're right, I wanted to keep it "one problem only" question, but now, in my real-world app the text that was below the image overlaps with it